# How to draw bar chart with range x-axis?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am using [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarChart) to draw charts.

Is there an option do draw bar chart with an x-axis like this?

```
    ***
    ***             ***
    ***     ***     *** 
    ***     ***     ***     ***
    ***     ***     ***     ***
 |  ***  |  ***  |  ***  |  ***  |
0am     1am     2am     3am     4am
```

I do not want to draw it this way:

```
  ***
  ***         ***
  ***   ***   ***
  ***   ***   ***   ***
  ***   ***   ***   ***
  ***   ***   ***   ***
  0am   1am   2am   3am
```

PS: [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarChart) is a wrapper for [nvd3](http://nvd3.org), which is a Re-usable charts for [d3.js](https://d3js.org).

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a clean way to do this. Not sure why you want to do it TBH - it looks a bit weird. But anyway - here's a hacky solution for NVD3 that you can port to AngularNVD3.

```
chart.rectClass('shift-right')
```

and then after you've done

```
d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(exampleData())
    .transition().duration(350)
    .call(chart);
```

Put

```
d3.selectAll('.shift-right').attr('x', '30');
```

This will shift all of the bars over by 30px.

http://jsfiddle.net/h7Lmkb4f/1/

Comment: "Not sure why you want to do it TBH": Data I want to display are between 2 dates, but not for a specific date. Example: "There were 130 active users from 3pm to 4pm".

Comment: I've found this but still have no clue how to use in using angular-nvd3 : https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histograms

Comment: For a histogram, it's just a bar chart with data pre-processed into bins. https://gist.github.com/daluu/6930fa129bffea638189